Applescript reporting syntax error. Automation script for excel using python, xlwings, VBA and applescript on macOS
The code aims to open an Excel spreadsheet, add VBA code (to create some buttons) and close the spreadsheet.
import subprocess

# This function is called at the end of another python file (everything else works fine, the error is right here)

def executeMAC():
    applescript = """
    tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    activate
    open "/---/---/---/registers2024.xlsx"

       tell workbook 1
           set vbaCode to "
           sub CreateButtons()
               Dim btnDate As Object
               Dim btnName As Object
               Dim btnShowAll As Object
               Dim ws As Worksheet
               Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(""Sheet1"")
    
               Set btnDate = ws.Buttons.Add(700, 50, 100, 30)
               btnDate.OnAction = ""DateFilter.DateFilter""
               btnDate.Caption = ""Filter by Date""
               btnDate.Placement = xlFreeFloating
    
               Set btnName = ws.Buttons.Add(700, 100, 100, 30)
               btnName.OnAction = ""NameFilter.NameFilter""
               btnName.Caption = ""Filter by Name""
               btnName.Placement = xlFreeFloating
    
               Set btnShowAll = ws.Buttons.Add(700, 150, 100, 30)
               btnShowAll.OnAction = ""ShowAllData.ShowAllData""
               btnShowAll.Caption = ""Show All Data""
               btnShowAll.Placement = xlFreeFloating
    
               Set btnGeneratePDF = ws.Buttons.Add(700, 200, 100, 30)
               btnGeneratePDF.OnAction = ""GeneratePDF.GeneratePDF""
               btnGeneratePDF.Caption = ""Generate PDF""
               btnGeneratePDF.Placement = xlFreeFloating
           End Sub
           "
           set vbModule to make new VB project at end
           tell vbModule
               make new VB component at end with properties {name:"CreateButtons", code content:vbaCode}
           end tell
       end tell
    
       save workbook 1 in "/---/---/---/registers2024.xlsm"
       close workbook 1

    end tell
    """

    # AppleScript Execute
    process = subprocess.run(\['osascript', '-e', applescript\], text=True)
    if process.returncode == 0:
        print('- VBA code inserted')
    else:
        print('- An error occurred while inserting VBA Code.')

The code returns the following error:
420:421: syntax error: Esperava-se final de linha, encontrou-se """. (-2741)
I've been reading and re-reading these lines for 2 days now. I've tried using chatGPT, but all it gives me is what I already know: AppleScript uses 2 double quotes to cancel them when there's code inside code - in this case, VBA inside AppleScript - and, apparently, I'm using it wrong somewhere, I just can't figure out where it is.
If anyone with more experience can help, please do.

Have you tried reducing this down to something much simpler?  Can you for example insert a Sub Hello: Msgbox "OK":End Sub instead of your much  longer code?  Can you save the AppleScript in a file and run it from there?

Why wrap the applescript with Python? Why not just run the applescript?

Robert, I didn't know AppleScript until now. I initially created this script on my pc (Windows) using Python, PyXL, Xlwings and VBA, and it works perfectly. But when I transferred it to the company computer (MacOS), the code didn't run. After doing a lot of research, I discovered that Xlwings used a Windows feature called COM that, obviously, didn't work on Mac. So I tried to replace just the part that didn't work in Python with AppleScript. Is it possible to make a script that reads .txt files from a folder and creates a stylized Excel spreadsheet with filter buttons using only AppleScript?

Tim Williams, these were just the last things I was trying earlier, before leaving the internship. Since I don't have a personal macbook, I'll only be able to continue testing tomorrow morning with the company one and I'll get back to you with an answer.

Two double quotes in AppleScript just represent an empty string.  If you want a double quote in a string it needs to be escaped, for example "\"cancel\"".
